# Boost not working on elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and confused at how the `_score` is calculated. I've tried to understand what's going on by reading some forum entries on the net ([here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/104728#104728) and [here](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/advanced-topics/scoring.html)) but still have some doubts and cannot fully resolve my problem.

**Aim**

Given some documents with fields `title` and `content`, find documents that match a `query`, with boosts for matches on the `title` field.

**The data**

```
PUT /sample/myType/1
{
    "title": "Blabbertalk here",
    "content": "Foobar here"
}

PUT /sample/myType/2
{
    "title": "Foobar here",
    "content": "Blabbertalk here"
}
```

**The query**

```
GET /sample/myType/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "title" : {
                            "query": "Blabbertalk",
                            "fuzziness": 0.7,
                            "boost": 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "content" : {
                            "query": "Blabbertalk",
                            "fuzziness": 0.7,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

**The result**

```
{
   "took": 21,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.095891505,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "sample",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.095891505,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Blabbertalk here",
               "content": "Foobar here"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "sample",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.095891505,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Foobar here",
               "content": "Blabbertalk here"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**The problem**

While this returns the right result on top, in another case it doesn't (which prompts me to ask this question). Nonetheless, this sample has same issues that confused me.

1. The two documents are scored very closely to each other (in fact, way too close). My expectation was document 1 should be scored much higher (like about doubled) as match happens on the `title` field
2. Running the same query with `?explain` parameter reveals that boost is not applied on the `_score` calculation (see below). It seems like Elasticsearch *does* recognize the boost factor (as illustrated by this line: `"description": "weight(title:blabbertalk^2.0 in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:"`), however, looking further into the details reveals that no boost factor is *actually* taken into score calculation.
3. Regarding the above issue, I draw suspicion on `title:blabbertalk^2.0 in 0`. What exactly does **in 0** mean? I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean "matched in 0 documents". Could it be that the **0** nullifies the boost? If so, is there a way to overcome this issue?

Last but not least, I realize this might not be Elasticsearch issue, because I believe Elasticsearch delegates this scoring and search task to Lucene in the back-end. However, I'm not too familiar with Lucene either, so I would really appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this.

Thank you very much for taking time to read such a long question and helping me out. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!

**Running the same query with explain parameter**

```
{
   "took": 40,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.095891505,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_shard": 2,
            "_node": "NaOynONhQWSvUmH77e_L9w",
            "_index": "sample",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.095891505,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Blabbertalk here",
               "content": "Foobar here"
            },
            "_explanation": {
               "value": 0.095891505,
               "description": "product of:",
               "details": [
                  {
                     "value": 0.19178301,
                     "description": "sum of:",
                     "details": [
                        {
                           "value": 0.19178301,
                           "description": "weight(title:blabbertalk^2.0 in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                           "details": [
                              {
                                 "value": 0.19178301,
                                 "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                 "details": [
                                    {
                                       "value": 1,
                                       "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 1,
                                             "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.30685282,
                                       "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.625,
                                       "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "value": 0.5,
                     "description": "coord(1/2)"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_shard": 3,
            "_node": "NaOynONhQWSvUmH77e_L9w",
            "_index": "sample",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.095891505,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Foobar here",
               "content": "Blabbertalk here"
            },
            "_explanation": {
               "value": 0.095891505,
               "description": "product of:",
               "details": [
                  {
                     "value": 0.19178301,
                     "description": "sum of:",
                     "details": [
                        {
                           "value": 0.19178301,
                           "description": "weight(content:blabbertalk in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                           "details": [
                              {
                                 "value": 0.19178301,
                                 "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                 "details": [
                                    {
                                       "value": 1,
                                       "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 1,
                                             "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.30685282,
                                       "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.625,
                                       "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "value": 0.5,
                     "description": "coord(1/2)"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solved this problem?

Comment: Same issue here.. Any reason why this happens yet?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got real solution to this particular problem :( not sure if newer releases of ES (relative to this question's post date) still have this problem or not.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the boost parameter should be placed in the match query itself, rather than within the field, like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "title" : {
                            "query": "Blabbertalk",
                            "fuzziness": 0.7
                        },
                        "boost": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "content" : {
                            "query": "Blabbertalk",
                            "fuzziness": 0.7
                        },
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Although you could simplify with a [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) instead:

```
{
    "multi_match" : {
        "query":      "Blabbertalk",
        "type":       "most_fields",
        "fields":     [ "title^2", "content" ],
        "fuzziness":  0.7
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but still stuck at the same problem. Putting `boost` in the match query produces error. It says the query is malformed.
And yes, you're right that my initial attempt can be written with a much simpler `multi_match` query instead (thanks for that!). Nonetheless, compared to my initial attempt it produces the exact same result, with the exact same `_score`, and the exact same score derivation as revealed by `explain`.